# Best way to determine issue with stored procedure performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Strored Procedure showing high number of reads in sql server profiler .

CPU of 335886
Reads of 261841162
Writes 7868
Duration 340510

This only happens with a certain account.

What is my 1st steps in determining the problem here ?

Stored Procedure tuning advice required ...

Comment: Can you show the execution path of the stored procedure? What differs this particular account from other accounts?

Comment: Maybe to view indexes?

Comment: Sorry a few access problems . Will do when I get access again to this box which may be tommorrow.

Comment: If it only happens for a certain account you may be experiencing parameter sniffing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **Database Engine Tuning Advisor**

1. Create a trace file using Sql Profiler
2. Use it a workload in Database Engine Tuning Advisor.
3. Try implementing the suggestion given by Database Engine Tuning Advisor.

After analyzing a workload, Database Engine Tuning Advisor can recommend that you add, remove, or modify physical design structures in your databases. The advisor can also recommend what statistics should be collected to back up physical design structures. The physical design structures include clustered indexes, nonclustered indexes, indexed views, and partitioning. Database Engine Tuning Advisor recommends a set of physical design structures that reduces the query optimizers estimated cost of the workload.

Refer this:

[Database Engine Tuning Advisor Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173494%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[Tutorial: Database Engine Tuning Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms166575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)